# Vertices selection tool

Tags: modeling

Hey i clicked something and now, in Edit mode, I have my mouse cursor as a cirles and it selects multiple vertices at once. How do I set the default one back please?
[image]

Comment: Use the escape key. This is a selection tool that you can activate with C key (circle select)

Comment: When i press "esc" or "C" nothing changes.

Comment: You turned on proportional editing. Press O (letter, not number) to turn it off.

Comment: It was some selecting mode. Changed with W.